# GCC: Getting ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 error on OS X 10.11.5

Tags: c++, gcc, vector

I've been trying to run a simple vector code that I saw on the internet to learn how vectors work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    /*  Initialize vector of 10 copies of the integer 5 */

    vector<int> vectorOne(10,5);

    /*  run through the vector and display each element, if possible */

    for (long index=0; index<20; ++index) {
        try {
            cout << "Element " << index << ": " << vectorOne.at(index) << endl;
        }
        catch (exception& e) {
            cout << "Element " << index << ": index exceeds vector dimensions." << endl;
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But every time I try to compile the code on the system, I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::allocate(unsigned long) in test1-6d0822.o
  "std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_out_of_range() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::at(unsigned long) in test1-6d0822.o
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in test1-6d0822.o
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in test1-6d0822.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in test1-6d0822.o
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in test1-6d0822.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in test1-6d0822.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in test1-6d0822.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::put(char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in test1-6d0822.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::flush()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in test1-6d0822.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in test1-6d0822.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in test1-6d0822.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)", referenced from:
      _main in test1-6d0822.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(long)", referenced from:
      _main in test1-6d0822.o
  "std::__1::cout", referenced from:
      _main in test1-6d0822.o
  "std::__1::ctype<char>::id", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in test1-6d0822.o
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in test1-6d0822.o
  "std::__1::locale::~locale()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in test1-6d0822.o
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in test1-6d0822.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in test1-6d0822.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in test1-6d0822.o
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in test1-6d0822.o
  "typeinfo for std::exception", referenced from:
      GCC_except_table0 in test1-6d0822.o
  "operator delete(void*)", referenced from:
      std::__1::__vector_base<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::~__vector_base() in test1-6d0822.o
  "operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::allocate(unsigned long) in test1-6d0822.o
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      _main in test1-6d0822.o
      ___clang_call_terminate in test1-6d0822.o
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in test1-6d0822.o
  "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
      _main in test1-6d0822.o
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in test1-6d0822.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      _main in test1-6d0822.o
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in test1-6d0822.o
      std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::vector(unsigned long, int const&) in test1-6d0822.o
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in test1-6d0822.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in test1-6d0822.o
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in test1-6d0822.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don't know what the problem is and would appreciate any help to understand what is going wrong, and if possible help me how to debug in the future. The problem lies in the declaration and usage of the vectors. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Command I used to compile is:

```
gcc test1.cpp -o test
```

the filename is test1.cpp

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code works fine for me using clang.
What is your command for compilation?

Try

```
g++ test1.cpp -o test
```

That works for me.

Comment: added the command for compilation

Comment: Try using the g++ command.

Comment: Ran into the same issue. Does anybody know why `g++` works but `clang` doesn't on a Mac?

Comment: Clang should work just fine. You tried the clang++ command?